# what's meaning for catch(exception) in c++ exception?

Tags: c++, exception

there are 3 types of exception:

(1) pointer

```
catch(exception* e){
}
```

(2) copy

```
catch(exception e){
}
```

(3) reference

```
catch(exception& e){
}
```

but what's the meaning for

```
catch(exception){
}
```

it it equal with (2) without no any difference in c++?

Comment: It's the same as (2); you just don't have a name with which to refer to the exception caught.

Comment: Same thing as unnamed parameters.

Comment: Never saw the first one unless it is just throwing a pointer.

Comment: @texasbruce: yes - it's just throwing a pointer.  Best practice is throwing by value and catching by `const` reference, which isn't even on this list....

Comment: @TonyD I mean if you throw a value of `T` but trying to catch by `T*`, it would not work. OP's statement is confusing because if you throw a `T*` and catch a `T*`, it is just catching by value (of pointer).

Comment: @texasbruce: yes, but if "exception" is a concrete type - specifically `std::exception` - and not a placeholder for arbitrary type `T`, it makes some sense to list it separately.  Anyway, catching by pointer raises ugly issues... must the catcher `delete` or `free` the object, or might it be a pointer to some static object or somehow owned by some exception-throwing library? If it's `new`ed/`malloc`ed, what if the allocation fails?  Could it be NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, it is possible to have a parameter without a variable name.

You should be able to have all of the following:

```
catch (std::exception* e) {}
catch (std::exception*) {}
catch (std::exception& e) {}
catch (std::exception&) {}
catch (std::exception e) {}
catch (std::exception) {}
```

A parameter without a variable name is a signal to the compiler that a parameter is required, but the value is unused in the method.